# Writing to a file with utf-8 path in java

Tags: java, utf-8, nio, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to Crypt some files in my program and it works fine but when I try to do it with a file whose path contains utf-8 letters it doesn't work and writes "FileNotFound Exception" then i tried to use java.nio maybe it could solve my issue but java.nio writes the same error :(
code: fil is the file i want to crypt, i want my buffer size be 50 mbytes (52428800 bytes) , x is the times that the buffer must be filled completely and y is the size that must be filled at the last time it fills buffer. example for a 101 mega bytes file y is 2 and x is 1 megabytes. the program read data from a channel to a buffer and then crypts it with a function that i didn't write here (thats not important my issue is the file path) and then puts it into a temp array and again writes it back to the file. when the path is ascii it works but when not it doesn't.------------------------------------if verifying the code is hard for you forget it. just tell me how to crypt a file with utf-8 name like  فایل.docx .

```
RandomAccessFile fil = new RandomAccessFile(sfil, "rw");

FileChannel inChannel = fil.getChannel();

ByteBuffer buf;
int x = (int) (fil.length() % (52428800));
int y = (int) (fil.length() / (52428800));
// -----------------------------------------
for (int q = 0; q <= y; q++) {
    if (q == y)
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(x);
    else
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(52428800);
    inChannel.read(buf);
    buf.flip();
    byte[] temp = new byte[buf.limit()];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.capacity(); i++) {
        temp[i] = cr(buf.get(), key);
    }
    buf.flip();
    buf.put(temp);
    while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
        inChannel.write(buf);
    }
    buf.clear();
}
inChannel.close();
fil.close();
```

Comment: This question would be much better if you included a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  As it stands, it looks like the problem is related to the value of `sfil` (and the contents of your filesystem) but we have no idea what either is...

Comment: Please read how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Which operating system and Java version do you use? How Java maps string file names to the file system depends on the system

Comment: I use windows 10 x64 and version:

java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: The wrong file name can have several causes. List the files in java and dump the bytes, the Unicode code points. Especially consider the LTR/RTL markers (Right-to-Left).

Comment: Use `vscode` this will help you to change the file encoding easily, just at the bottom of IDE, you will find the encodings, just change the encoding what ever you required